# RAW image data to Visible Image

Tags: python-3.x, ros2, realsense

I am trying to display a stream of raw image input from an Intel real-sense D435i camera. The dimensions settings on the camera are: 640 x 480 @ 30 FPS

I am trying to read the picture and move a robotic arm accordingly, is there a way to display that raw image input?

I tried to print the shape of the input, and it is a single list of integers.

I tried to look at openCV, but could not find what I was looking for, or maybe I did nt pay enough attention

Comment: have you tried visualizing using rviz?

Comment: I am trying to have everything running in the terminal. I have tried RVIZ, but that would not help me with what I want in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the real sense package for `ros2`

```
git clone https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros.git -b ros2-development
```

Then use `RVIZ2` to see it:

```
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2
```